# How do passive effects stack?

Tags: torchlight-2

I play an Outlander and have invested in passive Shadowling Ammo and Poison Burst, both of which may produce an effect upon enemy death. Let's assume I have a activation chance of 20% on both.

How are the effects evaluated?
Is it separately, meaning it is possible to have both the effects occur in a single event instance? [I.e. killing an enemy produces a poison burst and a shadowling.] That would also give me a 40% chance of at least one effect happening, and a 4% chance of both happening, I guess.

Or is it consecutively? If yes, it'd most probably work by evaluating one effect and only evaluating the other if the first failed. There are other possibilities, but from my observations I'd guess this be the case.
Or is it something else altogether?

Comment: Poison Burst and Shadowling Ammo cannot both happen off a single kill, as far as I know.  It may be they are sequential.